# componentDidMount firing before DOM is mounted when using createPortal in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code like this in my React application:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ComponentB from './ComponentB';

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.condition = this.props.condition;
    }

    render() {
         return ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <div id="abc"></div>,
            document.getElementById('xyz'))
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        ReactDOM.createPortal(
            <div>
                {

                    this.condition &&
                    <ComponentB />
                }
            </div>,
            document.body)
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to render `ComponentB` only after `ComponentA` has been mounted to DOM. Hence I have put the code for `ComponentA` inside `componentDidMount` of `ComponentB`. But still `ComponentB` is rendering before `ComponentA` has finished mounting to DOM.

Why is this happening and what's the solution to this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why you are using `createPortal`. But if you just want to achieve your goal, you just need to set your state condition in componentDidMount of first component telling to start rendering of your second component.

See if this helps.

```
const ComponentB = () => {

  return (
    <div>Hi is is componentB</div>
  );
}
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super (props);

    this.state = {
      renderB: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      renderB: true
    });
  }

  render () {
    let {renderB} = this.state;

    return (
      <div>

        <h3>Hey i am component A</h3>
        {
          renderB? <ComponentB /> : null
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using createPortal because I need to mount `ComponentB` outside  `ComponentA`. The solution you have provided will therefore not suffice my purpose.